spring Boot problem, In the database, when the data is entered, why is it not saved to the linked table , why is the foreign key null?

package com.example.project2.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "LoginUser")
public class LoginUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int loginID;

    private String loginEmail;
    private int loginContactNumber;
    private String loginPassword;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_reUserID", referencedColumnName = "reUserID")
    private RegisteredUser registeredUser;
}

package com.example.project2.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "RegisteredUser")
public class RegisteredUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int reUserID;

    private String reName;
    private String reEmail;
    private String reUserName;
    private String rePassword;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "registeredUser")
    private LoginUser loginUser;
}

package com.example.project2.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data

public class LoginUserDTO {
    private int loginID;
    private String loginEmail;
    private int loginContactNumber;
    private String loginPassword;
    private RegisteredUserDTO registeredUser;

}


package com.example.project2.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data

public class RegisteredUserDTO {
    private int reUserID;
    private String reName;
    private String reEmail;
    private String reUserName;
    private String rePassword;
}


package com.example.project2.service;
import com.example.project2.dto.LoginUserDTO;
import com.example.project2.dto.RegisteredUserDTO;
import com.example.project2.entity.LoginUser;
import com.example.project2.entity.RegisteredUser;
import com.example.project2.repo.LoginUserRepo;
import com.example.project2.repo.RegisteredUserRepo;
import com.example.project2.utill.VarList;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.TypeToken;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional

public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    private RegisteredUserRepo registeredUserRepo;

    public String saveRegisteredUser(RegisteredUserDTO registeredUserDTO){
        if (registeredUserRepo.existsById(registeredUserDTO.getReUserID())){
            return VarList.RSP_DUPLICATE;
        }else {
            registeredUserRepo.save(modelMapper.map(registeredUserDTO, RegisteredUser.class));
            return VarList.RSP_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private LoginUserRepo loginUserRepo;

    public String saveLoginUser(LoginUserDTO loginUserDTO){
        if (loginUserRepo.existsById(loginUserDTO.getLoginID())){
            return VarList.RSP_DUPLICATE;
        }else {
            loginUserRepo.save(modelMapper.map(loginUserDTO, LoginUser.class));
            return VarList.RSP_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    
}

package com.example.project2.controller;

import com.example.project2.dto.*;
import com.example.project2.repo.LoginUserRepo;
import com.example.project2.repo.RegisteredUserRepo;
import com.example.project2.service.ProjectService;
import com.example.project2.utill.VarList;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/project")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    private ResponseDTO responseDTO;

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveEmployee")
    public ResponseEntity saveEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
        try {
            String res= projectService.saveEmployee(employeeDTO);
            if (res.equals("00")){
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_SUCCESS);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Success");
                responseDTO.setContemt(employeeDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

            }else if(res.equals("06")){
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_DUPLICATE);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Employee registered");
                responseDTO.setContemt(employeeDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }else {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_FAIL);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Error");
                responseDTO.setContemt(null);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_ERROR);
            responseDTO.setMassage("Success");
            responseDTO.setContemt(null);
            return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private AdminRepo adminRepo;

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveAdmin")
    public ResponseEntity saveAdmin(@RequestBody AdminDTO adminDTO){
        try {
            String res = projectService.saveAdmin(adminDTO);
            if(res.equals("00")){
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_SUCCESS);
                responseDTO.setMassage("succes");
                responseDTO.setContemt(adminDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

            } else if (res.equals("06")) {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_DUPLICATE);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Employee registerd");
                responseDTO.setContemt(adminDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            }else {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_FAIL);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Error");
                responseDTO.setContemt(adminDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_ERROR);
            responseDTO.setMassage("Success");
            responseDTO.setContemt(adminDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
   

    @Autowired
    private RegisteredUserRepo registeredUserRepo;

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveRegisteredUser")
    public ResponseEntity saveRegisteredUser(@RequestBody RegisteredUserDTO registeredUserDTO){
        try {
            String res = projectService.saveRegisteredUser(registeredUserDTO);
            if(res.equals("00")){
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_SUCCESS);
                responseDTO.setMassage("succes");
                responseDTO.setContemt(registeredUserDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

            } else if (res.equals("06")) {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_DUPLICATE);
                responseDTO.setMassage("RegisteredUser registerd");
                responseDTO.setContemt(registeredUserDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            }else {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_FAIL);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Error");
                responseDTO.setContemt(registeredUserDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_ERROR);
            responseDTO.setMassage("Success");
            responseDTO.setContemt(registeredUserDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
  
    @Autowired
    private LoginUserRepo loginUserRepo;

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveLoginUser")
    public ResponseEntity saveLoginUser(@RequestBody LoginUserDTO loginUserDTO){
        try {
            String res = projectService.saveLoginUser(loginUserDTO);
            if(res.equals("00")){
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_SUCCESS);
                responseDTO.setMassage("succes");
                responseDTO.setContemt(loginUserDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

            } else if (res.equals("06")) {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_DUPLICATE);
                responseDTO.setMassage("LoginUser registerd");
                responseDTO.setContemt(loginUserDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            }else {
                responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_FAIL);
                responseDTO.setMassage("Error");
                responseDTO.setContemt(loginUserDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            responseDTO.setCode(VarList.RSP_ERROR);
            responseDTO.setMassage("Success");
            responseDTO.setContemt(loginUserDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity(responseDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

I make two tables named, LoginUser and RegisteredUser. then connected two tables with a foreign key. then I created save methods for above class. Then I called saveLOginUser method in postman using an Api. Then I entered a dataset for the two tables, but data is only saved in the LoginUser table and not in the RegisteredUser table, also the primary key is null. Why data is not saved in the RegisterUser table.

Can you add/include LoginUserDTO class?

The problem you're facing is because of the mapping your mapper doesn't map the nester registeredUserDTO because I've tested your code with the following mapper, and it's working properly:
public class LoginUserMapperImpl implements LoginUserMapper {

    @Override
    public LoginUserDTO toDTO(LoginUser loginUser) {
        if (loginUser == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LoginUserDTO loginUserDTO = new LoginUserDTO();

        loginUserDTO.setLoginID(loginUser.getLoginID());
        loginUserDTO.setLoginEmail(loginUser.getLoginEmail());
        loginUserDTO.setLoginContactNumber(loginUser.getLoginContactNumber());
        loginUserDTO.setLoginPassword(loginUser.getLoginPassword());
        loginUserDTO.setRegisteredUser(registeredUserToRegisteredUserDTO(loginUser.getRegisteredUser()));

        return loginUserDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public LoginUser toEntity(LoginUserDTO loginUserDTO) {
        if (loginUserDTO == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser();

        loginUser.setLoginID(loginUserDTO.getLoginID());
        loginUser.setLoginEmail(loginUserDTO.getLoginEmail());
        loginUser.setLoginContactNumber(loginUserDTO.getLoginContactNumber());
        loginUser.setLoginPassword(loginUserDTO.getLoginPassword());
        loginUser.setRegisteredUser(registeredUserDTOToRegisteredUser(loginUserDTO.getRegisteredUser()));

        return loginUser;
    }

    protected RegisteredUserDTO registeredUserToRegisteredUserDTO(RegisteredUser registeredUser) {
        if (registeredUser == null) {
            return null;
        }

        RegisteredUserDTO registeredUserDTO = new RegisteredUserDTO();

        registeredUserDTO.setReUserID(registeredUser.getReUserID());
        registeredUserDTO.setReName(registeredUser.getReName());
        registeredUserDTO.setReEmail(registeredUser.getReEmail());
        registeredUserDTO.setReUserName(registeredUser.getReUserName());
        registeredUserDTO.setRePassword(registeredUser.getRePassword());

        return registeredUserDTO;
    }

    protected RegisteredUser registeredUserDTOToRegisteredUser(RegisteredUserDTO registeredUserDTO) {
        if (registeredUserDTO == null) {
            return null;
        }

        RegisteredUser registeredUser = new RegisteredUser();

        registeredUser.setReUserID(registeredUserDTO.getReUserID());
        registeredUser.setReName(registeredUserDTO.getReName());
        registeredUser.setReEmail(registeredUserDTO.getReEmail());
        registeredUser.setReUserName(registeredUserDTO.getReUserName());
        registeredUser.setRePassword(registeredUserDTO.getRePassword());

        return registeredUser;
    }
}

The mapper is generated by MapStruct. Try adding the following dependencies to your pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Then, create the mapper interface:
package com.example.project2.mapper;

import com.example.project2.dto.LoginUserDTO;
import com.example.project2.entity.LoginUser;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface LoginUserMapper {
    LoginUserDTO toDTO(LoginUser loginUser);
    LoginUser toEntity(LoginUserDTO loginUserDTO);
}

You can then inject the mapper where needed:
@Autowired
private LoginUserMapper loginUserMapper;

Note: Be careful when using MapStruct with Lombok, you can refer to this if you encounter any issues when adding MapStruct with Lombok:  mapstruct with Lombok

If I add new entities, each entity should be coded as above.

The problem you're facing is due to the mapping just try to use a mapping library like mapstruct or write the mapping by hand
